# Python re.sub giving error: invalid group reference

Tags: python, regex

I know this was covered elsewhere but my use case is causing me difficulty.

What if a string has a dreaded "\3" character like this one:

```
new_data = r'C:\temp\3_times.csv'
```

...then re "thinks" that you're referring to it as a group so if you try to do a sub using that data then you get this error:

```
newfiledata = re.sub(old_data,new_data,filedata)

error: invalid group reference
```

Is there any way to avoid this error without looking for that case in the string and modifying it directly before passing it which would take lots of extra code.

Note: For the usage I'm going for modifying the string with escape characters isn't an option because I need to write the string with the sub function later on. So this is not a duplicate of the question on how to escape special characters.

Comment: In any regex, literal backslashes have to be escaped. As a regex it would be `r'C:\\temp\\3_times\.csv'` What you should do is to escape metachars of your regex literals. You can do a sub using `r'([.^#|*+?()\[\]{}\\-])'` replace with `\\$1`

Comment: @sln doesn't `r` make it a raw string, and make it unnecessary to escape your slashes? or is that not the case?

Comment: @jacoblaw - it's what you're passing to the regex engine. All literal metacharacters have to be escaped.

Comment: Sorry, that should be sub using `r'([.^$|*+?()\[\]{}\\-])'` replace with `\\$1`

Comment: Looks like re.escape() uses `\W` which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `re.escape()`:

```
import re
new_data = re.escape('C:\temp\3_times.csv')
```

... which escapes special characters, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for more information.

Comment: `Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed` I wouldn't use this. It's equivalent to `\W`, escapes all metachars, but also escapes control, whitespace, and probably a large swath of Unicode.

Comment: This returns: 'C\\:\\\temp\\\x03_times\\.csv'...which serves the purpose of escaping the meta characters, however since it modifies the string it defeats the purpose of using it with the sub method to write the data.